# finding where my log files are being sent to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In my company we are storing log files in cloudwatch and then after 7days it will get sent to s3 however I have trouble finding exactly where log files are being stored in s3.

Since process of moving from cloudwatch to s3 is automated I've followed https://medium.com/tensult/exporting-of-aws-cloudwatch-logs-to-s3-using-automation-2627b1d2ee37 in hope to find the path.

We are not using step functions so I've check lambda services however there were no function that move log file from cloudwatch to s3.

I've tried looking at cloudwatch rules in hope to fine something like:

```
{
    "region":"REGION",
    "logGroupFilter":"prod",
    "s3BucketName":"BUCKET_NAME",
    "logFolderName":"backend"
}
```

so I can find which bucket log files are going to and into which folder.

How can I find where my logs are stored, if moving data is being automated why is there no functions visible?

addtional note: I am new to aws, if there is good resource on aws architecture please recommend.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If the rule exists or was created properly then you must see it in the AWS console and same is the true for S3 bucket.

One common problem when it comes to visibility of an asset in AWS console is wrong region selection. So verify in which region the rule and the S3 bucket was created, if they were ever created and selecting the right region on the top right corner should show the assets in that region.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am in the correct region. I've check other regions and they have empty lambda functions. Could it be because I do not have permission?

Comment: lambda function, cloudwatch, s3 are all region specific resources. You will see them in the same region as you created them. Are you able to locate the lambda function in your desired region? Maybe lambda is not even created and executed

Comment: If there is no lambda how does log file get sent from cloudwatch to s3?

Comment: or maybe logs are being sent straight from server to both s3 and cloudwatch?

Comment: You must be pushing the logs to the cloudwatch. And then in cloudwatch you must have created a rule to send the logs in the S3. I thought you created that rule using a lamdba.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `View all exports to Amazon S3` in the CloudWatch -> >Logs console.  It is one of the items in the Actions menu.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I've checked however it says No tasks